# Swift - jonkykong SideMenu - Push view on top of menu

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I'm using jonkykong's SideMenu and I want to push a view controller on top of my menu without dismissing the menu. Setting `menuDismissOnPush` to false keeps the menu from dismissing, but the pushed view controller is underneath the menu. How can I force it on top of the menu?

```
/**
Automatically dismisses the menu when another view is pushed from it.

 Note: to prevent the menu from dismissing when presenting, set modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
 of the view controller being presented in storyboard or during its initalization.
 */
open var menuDismissOnPush = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code
 `SideMenuManager.default.menuPushStyle = .subMenu`